# Including environment variables in uWSGI ini files?

Tags: configuration, environment-variables, ini, uwsgi, env

I am using .ini files (as per [uWSGI docs](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Configuration.html#ini-files)). It's good practise to use environment variables, but I wasn't able to get the `$`+`environment name` syntax working.

Is there a special syntax I can use to access them?

Answer (score 17):

The syntax is `$(var)`, for example:

```
chdir = $(HOME)/foobar
```

See also [How uWSGI parses config files](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ParsingOrder.html).

Comment: Is there a way to have a default (in case the env var is not set)?

Comment: @roberto, also wondering about what David is asking.  For example if I wanted to set the value for `threads` from an environment variable, but fall back to the default (1 thread per process) if the environment variable is not defined...?

Answer (score 2):

contents of evironment variables and external text files can be included using the $(ENV_VAR) and @(file_name) syntax. [See also How uWSGI parses config files.](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ParsingOrder.html)